# Multiple column updates in one statement - Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update three columns depending on three different conditions in Microsoft SQL Server. See the following example for details

```
UPDATE s 
SET s.Column1 = NULL 
FROM #My_Temp_Table s  
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(S.Column1, 0)) = 0 
     
UPDATE s 
SET s.Column2 = NULL 
FROM #My_Temp_Table s  
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(S.Column2, 0)) = 0 

UPDATE s 
SET s.Column3 = NULL 
FROM #My_Temp_Table s  
WHERE ISNUMERIC(ISNULL(S.Column3, 0)) = 0
```

How would I refactor the query if I want to do it in one update statement? Appreciate your help!

Comment: If you want to ensure the column has numerical data, why are you not defining it with a numerical data type?

Comment: @marc_s - What about using `CASE WHEN` in assignment expressions?

Comment: As an aside, `ISNUMERIC` is a bad function you generally should not use. It thinks all sorts of things are "numeric" where most sensible folk would disagree, like `-`, `$` and `.` (which are all valid strings for *some* numeric types in T-SQL, though crucially not for *all* numeric types). Prefer `TRY_CONVERT` or constructs like `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` for simple cases of integers.

Comment: @marc_s: No `WHERE` at all. Each assignment: `SET b=CASE WHEN <cond> THEN NULL ELSE b END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the where clauses. And we can take advantage of the fact that `TRY_CONVERT()` will yield `NULL` if the value can't be converted to the target type. (I'm guessing you want to make sure they're *integers*, but you can replace `int` below with any numeric type.)

```
UPDATE #My_Temp_Table 
  SET Column1 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column1),
      Column2 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column2),
      Column3 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column3);
```

You can add the `WHERE` clauses, but since you need to use `OR` and return any row that matches any of the three criteria, you're likely better off just scanning once as above:

```
UPDATE #My_Temp_Table 
  SET Column1 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column1),
      Column2 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column2),
      Column3 = TRY_CONVERT(int, Column3)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(int, Column1) IS NULL
   OR TRY_CONVERT(int, Column2) IS NULL
   OR TRY_CONVERT(int, Column3) IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Been bothering me for a week and I had been avoiding asking the question. But the answer is well written.

Comment: Do note that this involves a conversion back to string again -- this means it doesn't necessarily round-trip. The string `'+ 123'` will be converted to `'123'`. This isn't likely to be a problem assuming the ultimate goal is indeed to get `INT` values, but still worth being aware of. If no conversion is desired at this point, something like `SET Column1 = CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int, Column1) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Column1 END` is needed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's a good point, thanks. I'm assuming the point is to get rid of `'garbage'`.